# CSS FlexBox Not Centering Horizontally Within IE On vBulletin Forum

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have attempted to align four images/links using Flexbox for a simple banner row. It works fine within Chrome and FF, but within IE 11, the Flexbox seems to fail as the images stack vertically rather than horizontally.

You can view the row of images here:
http://bit.ly/1KZ20hf

They are near the top where it reads, "Popular RPF Pulse Posts:" Notice how in IE, the banners stop being aligned horizontally.

On my local drive and on a non vBulletin forum site there are no issues within IE when I test out the banner code. So I am wondering if dropping the code within the vBulletin framework is causing issues for IE 11. Any insights would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

CSS that the banner row uses is below:

```css
.sgFlexBox {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.sgFlexItemFooter {
    width: 205px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 12px 15px 12px;
    text-align: center;
} 
.rpfPostLink {
    color: #FFF;
    font: bold 15px/21px Arial;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
}
.sgFlexIcon {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border: 2px solid #d2d2d2;
}
#sgCenterTitle {
    color: #FFF;
    font: bold 18px/18px Arial;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0 10px 0
}
```

Comment: I am viewing it on IE 11.

Comment: Sorry, weekend interrupts play. If you open up Dev Tools (F12) is the version dropdown at right-top displaying Edge or something else?

Comment: No worries Karl - appreciate your response! I did as you said and the version dropdown that is selected is 9 (default). I noticed that if I select Edge the banners properly display horizontally. I assume selecting Edge shows how the new Windows 10 browser renders a page?

Comment: That's right. I *think* because you are using a Transitional DOCTYPE, IE goes into old school mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transitional DOCTYPE causes IE Edge to emulate IE9 and unfortunately CSS `flexbox` is [unsupported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) by that version.

Comment: Interesting. I gather vBulletin adds that automatically at the top in one of the top page php templates. Curious, what DOCTYPE would you recommend to use?

Comment: Well ordinarily it's all about HTML5 now so that would be `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Transitional exists because it indicated a possible mix of HTML4 with older presentational markup. If it will let you, try `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"             "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">` before `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: Thanks Karl - understanding why IE was having issues with the flexbox code was very helpful. If banners remain up - hopefully an implementation of the fix can occur and do the trick in fixing the issue.

Comment: No worries, my not-so-inner geek is delighted to "contribute" to the awesomeness of that particular forum lol